# Tkinter Config Errors

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tkinter returns error when using config. For example I made a button on my frame have a bg="black" and it will throw the error.

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"

I have tried to use both

```
b = Button(self.menuFrame, Text="Test", bg="black")
```

and

```
b.config(bg="black")
```

Both throw the same error.

```
class Run(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Run, self).__init__(master)

        # | Variables |
        self.cur_frame = 0
        self.t = ""

        # | Frames |
        self.frames = []
        for i in range(2):
            self.frames.append(i)
        self.frames[0] = self.loadFrame = Frame(self)
        self.frames[1] = self.mainFrame = Frame(self)

        # | Widgets |
        self.load_widgets()
        self.menu_widgets()

        # | Main |
        self.grid()
        self.frames[1].grid()

    def go_frame(self, frame):
        if frame != self.cur_frame:
            self.frames[self.cur_frame].grid_remove()
            self.frames[frame].grid()
            self.cur_frame = frame

    def load_widgets(self):
        pass

    def menu_widgets(self):
        self.t = Text(self.frames[1], width=63, height=37, bg='#847676', state=DISABLED)
        self.t.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=6, sticky="nsew")

        b_start = Button(self.frames[1], text='Start', command=lambda: self.daily())
        b_stop = Button(self.frames[1], text='Stop', command=lambda: self.stop())
        b_run1 = Button(self.frames[1], text='Run Exp', command=lambda: self.run(1))
        b_run2 = Button(self.frames[1], text='Run Scan', command=lambda: self.run(4))
        b_run3 = Button(self.frames[1], text='Run Inc', command=lambda: self.run(7))
        b_config = Button(self.frames[1], text='Config', command=lambda: self.go_frame(0))
        s_bar = Scrollbar(self.frames[1], command=self.t.yview)
        s_bar.config(bg="#403939")

        b_start.grid(row=0, column=0)
        b_stop.grid(row=1, column=0)
        b_run1.grid(row=2, column=0)
        b_run2.grid(row=3, column=0)
        b_run3.grid(row=4, column=0)
        b_config.grid(row=5, column=0)
        s_bar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='nsew', rowspan=6)
        self.t['yscrollcommand'] = s_bar.set

app = Tk()
app.config(bg='#403939')

w = 600
h = 600
ws = app.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = app.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((ws/2) - (w/2))
y = int((hs/2) - (h/2))

app.geometry()
app.geometry(f'{w}x{h}+{x}+{y}')

Run(app)
app.mainloop()
```

I would expect this to make the scrollbar the colour I have set as I have used this method before in python 3.4. Currently running on python 3.7 and it gives me errors for the config on tk widgets. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported ttk?

Comment: These are my imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

Comment: Use `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import ttk` instead. Then create your button using `tk.Button` which has the `bg` config.

Comment: In the future please provide your imports in your question. That is actually where your problem lies and no one can test or know for sure without your imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your imports look like this

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

Both `tkinter` and `ttk` have a `Button` class and because you use wildcard imports (`*`) they both should be imported as `Button`. Because two different objects cannot have the same name, the `ttk` `Button` overwrites the `tkinter` `Button` since it is imported later.

So when you do `b = Button(...)`, you're not using the `tkinter` version but the `ttk` version of `Button`, which as the error says doesn't have a `bg` option.

To prevent confusions like these, avoid wildcard imports. Instead, have your imports like

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
```

You can then use the `tkinter` `Button` like `b = tk.Button(...)` and the `ttk` button like `b = ttk.Button(...)`

---

P.S. If you *do* want to use the `ttk` `Button`, [use `ttk.Style()` to change its appearance](https://web.archive.org/web/20190509211714/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html).